# Alternatives to Skew Normal Distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, skew-normal-distribution

I'm fitting a model (using MLE) on a data set that is left-skewed. I was originally using a Gaussian log likelihood function but have been investigating whether it's possible to use [Skewed Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) (SN) instead. The trouble is, the PDF of SN contains the CDF of a regular Normal distribution which is hard to calculate.

[image: PDF of SN]

Is there an alternative to SN where the likelihood function is a bit easier to deal with? As background, my model is actually a neural net and I'm interested in the mean, variance and skewness of the distribution.

Comment: What is negatively skewed? We tend not to care about the pooled distribution of the response variable ($y$).

Comment: Sorry I meant left skewed. What do you mean by pooled distribution?

Comment: Left-skewed and negatively skewed are one and the same. subject to small print that there can be distributions that look left-skewed but that score zero or positive on some measure(s) of skewness. More importantly, I think @Dave is referring to the fact that the marginal distribution of the response variable is rarely crucial to modelling.

Comment: We need more information about your data and objectives before we can supply reasoned advice.